# How include file in Android apps internal storage (App-specific storage)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maui

I need to include a file with my app build.  So the file gets placed in my apps **internal** storage (e.g. `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app1/files/mydb.db`).  As best I can tell from researching, I either have to put it in Assets and copy it out when my app runs the first time - or I'll have to download it the first time my app runs.  The 1st approach would be inefficient (ends up with 2 copies of db).  The 2nd is annoying workaround.

I'm coming from C++ Builder where with a [Firemonkey](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/fm-application-platform) mobile app all I have to do is specify in the Deployment tab of the IDE that the file be installed in internal storage.

[image]

That doesn't seem to be possible with VS 2022 and Xamarin Forms.

[image]

I just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly (I'm new to VS and Xamarin Forms).

Comment: AFAIK this is a restriction of iOS and Android, not VS or Xamarin.  I’d be curious to know how Firemonkey gets around it

Comment: My sentiment exactly.

Comment: my best guess would be that they automatically handle copying the file from the app bundle to the file system at startup